Advanced PDF If else condition to return a specific value
I am trying to create a PDF Template for a saved search which returns value Store Signature in an instance where my custom form is Store Requisition and returns Supervisor Signature if any other form name appears. My code only returns Supervisor Signature and doesn't respect the condition.
<#if results?size != 0>
    <table style="padding: 0.2in 0.01in 0.01in 0.02in; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1.5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:9pt">
                    <#assign signatureSet = false>
                    
                    <#list results as result>
                        <#if !signatureSet && result.formulatext_1??>                                <#assign customform = result.formulatext_1>
                            
                            <#if customform == "Stock Requisition">
                                <p>Stores Signature:</p>
                                <#assign signatureSet = true>
                            <#else>
                                <p>Supervisor Signature:</p>
                                <#assign signatureSet = true>
                            </#if>
                        </#if>
                    </#list>
                    <#if !signatureSet>
                        <p>Supervisor Signature</p>
                    </#if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</#if>


I don't think customform is value all by itself.
Maybe: <#if result.customform == "Stock Requisition">
Also, just in case, result.formulatext_1 refers to the second formula text column in your results.
